# PassthroughSubject with no initial value

Tags: swift, combine

I want to create a Swift Combine publisher that transmits a value and always gives the latest value when someone subscribes to it. However I want to only transmit a value once I have one - from an asynchronous call that’s triggered by the first subscriber. Pass through subject doesn’t work for that need, is there any good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would you provide your code?

Comment: This is not difficult but it would help if you would explain the phrase "from an asynchronous call that’s triggered by the first subscriber". Can you be more specific?

Comment: “from an asynchronous call“—How does it provide the value? Does it call a callback? “always gives the latest value”—How do you obtain the second and later values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CurrentValueSubject` for this:

```
let subject = CurrentValueSubject<T, E>(someValue)

func whatever() -> AnyPublisher<T, E> {
  return subject.dropFirst().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```